# Soma dos números pares e multiplicação de números impares num intervalo

Tags: c, algoritmo

> Leia dois numeros sendo que y maior que x, calcular a soma dos números
>   pares desse intervalo de números, incluindo os números digitados;
>   calcular e mostrar a multiplicação dos números ímpares desse
>   intervalo, incluindo os digitados;

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <locale.h>
 int main ()
 {
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");
 int X=0, Y=0,somapar=0, cont=0, impar;


printf("Insira o VALOR DE X: ");
scanf("%d", &X);
printf("Insira o VALOR DE Y: ");
scanf("%d", &Y);


if (Y>X)
{

   for (cont=X; cont<=Y; cont++)
{
cont;

 if (cont%2==0)
 {
 somapar = somapar + cont;
  }

  else
  { 
  impar = impar * cont;
   }

}
   }
  else
   {
    printf("X não pode ser maior que Y\n");
     }
    printf("A soma dos números pares nesse intervalo é %d\n", somapar);
    printf("A multiplicação dos números impares nesse intervalo é %d\n", impar);

  system ("pause");
   return 0;
     }
```

Colocando 0 para X e 10 para Y, a saída mostra apenas a soma dos números pares que dá 30, mas a multiplicação dá zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A multiplicação dá zero porque não foi iniciada:

```
int X=0, Y=0,somapar=0, cont=0, impar;
```

Um vez que vai multiplicar deve iniciar o `impar` com o valor neutro da multiplicação, o 1:

```
int X=0, Y=0,somapar=0, cont=0, impar = 1;
```

Agora já funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Achei q ja tivesse tentado isso kkkkkkkk foi, valeu!!!

Answer (score 3):

Eu já estava com a resposta quase pronta quando tive que parar. Estou postando assim mesmo já que tem o código executando e mais organizado e simplificado.

O erro principal era não ter inicializado a variável `impar` com valor 1. Poderia acontecer duas coisas. Ter o valor 0 e aí qualquer multiplicação daria 0. Ou pegar um valor qualquer que estava na memória, o que daria muito errado e pareceria uma loucura. Em C sempre inicialize as variáveis, a não ser que saiba o que está fazendo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int X = 0, Y = 0, par = 0, impar = 1;
    printf("Insira o VALOR DE X: ");
    scanf("%d", &X);
    printf("Insira o VALOR DE Y: ");
    scanf("%d", &Y);
    if (Y <= X) {
        printf("X não pode ser maior que Y\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int cont = X; cont <= Y; cont++) {
        if (cont % 2 == 0) par += cont;
        else impar *= cont;
    }
    printf("A soma dos números pares nesse intervalo é %d\n", par);
    printf("A multiplicação dos números impares nesse intervalo é %d\n", impar);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/b47FX7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vlhgvepj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Multiply.c).

Comment: Eu tinha inicializado todas as variaveis, porem tudo igual a 0. E deu o que vc falou, a saida da multiplicação dava 0. Até tentei colocar impar = 1, mas acho que quando fiz isso tinha mais de um erro e por isso tbem deu 0. kkkkkkkk No fim deu tudo certo. Obrigado pela explicação!